# How do I exclude all .DS_Store files from Perforce?

Tags: perforce, perforce-client-spec

I use the graphic interface in Perforce to set up an exclusion for .DS_Store files:

[image]

It makes this in the workspace:

`-//depot/*.DS_Store    //almo_SilentMac/*.DS_Store`

But when I do Reconcile Offline Work, it still comes up with .DS_Store files. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why not a specific filename of `.DS_Store` ?

Comment: I agree with @thrig. `.DS_Store` isn't an extension, it's a filename, so use the "specific filename" entry instead.

Comment: Same behavior with `-//depot/.DS_Store //almo_SilentMac/.DS_Store`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The '*' wildcard only matches a single string of characters NOT including the directory separator, so to match a file named .DS_Store at any level in your folder tree use the '...' wildcard instead, as in:

```
-//depot/.../.DS_Store //almo_SilentMac/.../.DS_Store
```

Alteratively, and possibly easier, consider using a P4IGNORE file: http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/P4IGNORE.html

Comment: Seems strange the dialog for creating these rules doesn't generate this correct config line.